# Delay when switching modes

Tags: vim, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-12.10

When using vim in gnome-terminal there is a 1s delay after pressing <Esc> to go back to normal mode.

I tried Google and found ttimeoutlen.
I tried setting it to 100 with no effect (delay is still that of timeoutlen).

I am using latest Vim on Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have any mappings that start with `<esc>`? (Run this command within vim):

```
:imap <esc>
```

Does it still happen when you start Vim without any initialization files? (Run this on a shell command line):

```
vim -u NONE -U NONE --noplugin -N
```